# Umbraco - web.config issue when installing

Tags: iis, umbraco

I'm trying to install a default Umbraco installation on IIS7, and I'm getting the following error on my (unmodified) web.config file, any ideas?

**Config Error
The configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration**

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you installing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using the current version of Umbraco 4.5.2 as offered on the Codeplex site...

By default, Umbraco is configured to use .Net 2.0 (not .Net 4.0). Go to your IIS Management Console, select ApplicationPools and double-click your website. Make sure the .Net Framework is set to 2.0.

Also make sure the server you are running the IIS on has .Net 2.0 installed!

If you can provide more information from the server's error page, I can help better pinpoint the error...

Comment: The "default" download nowadays is actually the .net 4 version. So either switch the app pool to 4 or 2. Whichever it is not on right now. :-)